# spring jms - perform action before message received

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms, mdc

Is it possible to perform an action before a jms message is received in spring boot?  I know I could put it at the very top of my `@JmsListener`, but I have several listeners and I'd prefer avoiding adding a call to all of them.

I'm trying to use the logging `MDC` (a threadlocal, if you're not familiar with the MDC,) to track various things and I'd like to set some properties before beginning to process the message.  I can do this on my controllers with a `Filter`, but does spring jms have the same concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to start with an Before or Around (in case there should be some logic implemented after handling message as well) aspect:

```
@Before("@annotation(JmsListener)")
public void handle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) { ... }

@Around("@annotation(JmsListener)")
public void handle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) { ... }
```

Couple of links: [enabling aspectj support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-enable-aspectj-java), [before advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-advice-before), [around advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice).